# Broadcasting mouse movements through Websockets

Tags: node.js, html, websocket, mousemove

I have implemented a simple "online whiteboard" using Nodejs on the server side, and websockets on the client side.

A "master" sends mouse coords to all the other connected clients.
Extremely simplified:

client..

```
whiteboard.onmousemove = 
function()
{
 Client_Send({x:event.pageX, y:event.pageY});
}
```

server..

```
socket.on("text") =
function(text)
{
 // ...GET A LIST OF CONNECTED USERS MINUS THE MASTER...
 Broadcast(users, text); 
}
```

The problem:

- If I send every single mouse movement, the clients appear to get "flooded" with updates, with messages arriving in clusters of 5-10, then a hiccup, then more clustered messages
- If send an update only every few milliseconds, (ex. using setInterval rather than sending upon every single MouseMove event), I still get some clustering, even with just 8-10 updates per second

Is there some fundamental of websockets that I am missing here? (Using them for the first time)

Comment: How frequently do you send the movement? Do you have some sort of debounce/delay?

Comment: Case 1: Every single onmousemove event (no debouncing - I assume that a onmousemove event won't happen unless the coords have changed)  Case 2: On a regular schedule of (1000/8) milliseconds (With debouncing: if the coords haven't changed, I don't send an update)

Comment: Have you checked the `ulimit` on your socket server? Are you using some sort of load balancer or a reverse proxy between your client and server?

Comment: No load balancers or reverse proxies. I will check on the "ulimit" setting - I am not sure. I have implemented a very simple server and for the websockets implementation I am relying on nodejs-websocket (https://inch-ci.org/github/sitegui/nodejs-websocket)

Comment: You might also see improvements if you fine-tune your max buffer length -
 See https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket#wssetmaxbufferlengthbytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the hiccup was created by flood protection policies configured on the Server's firewall. We never figured out how to configure policies so to protect from malicious flood but allow legit traffic, however disabling such policies entirely solved the bottleneck.